# How to Save Inspect Element Changes?

Tags: google-chrome, html, javascript

I'm trying to change the dimensions of the DIV frame

[image: DIV frame]

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a folder to the workspace and then you will be able to save the files to that folder.

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6843535/475536) exactly how to do it.